# sorting in mongodb aggregation according to timestamp

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

i have this collection

{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "28", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:12:42" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "30", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:12:42" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "32", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:12:42" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "29", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:12:42" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "31", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:12:42" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "28", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:14:16" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "29", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:16:33" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "32", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:14:09" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "28", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:16:33" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "30", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:14:16" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "31", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:16:33" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "29", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:14:16" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "30", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:16:33" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "31", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:14:16" }
{ "ip" : "192.168.141.1", "ifsIndex" : "32", "link" : "1", "timeStamp" : "19-01-2018 18:16:33" }

i want to group ip address and ifsIndex together  and show the array of link and timeStamp and show the result in sorted timestamp.i tried this

```
db.events.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"ifIndex":"$ifsIndex","ip":"$ip"},status:{$push:"$link"},timeStamp:{$push:"$timeStamp"}}},{$sort:{"timeStamp":1}}])
```

result i get is not i want. some values are not sorted in timeStamp

```
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "31", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:16:33", "19-01-2018 18:14:16" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "29", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:16:33", "19-01-2018 18:14:16" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "32", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:09", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "30", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:16", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "28", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:16", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
```

the timeStamp of ifIndex 31 and 29 are not sorted and others are sorted. what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: First change timestamp from string to date or use ISO format string. Do you want to sort the timestamp inside each array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sort` the timestamp and then do `$group` to get the `$push` sorted

```
db.events.aggregate(
    [   
        {$sort:{"timeStamp":1}},
        {$group:{_id:{"ifIndex":"$ifsIndex","ip":"$ip"},status:{$push:"$link"},timeStamp:{$push:"$timeStamp"}}}

    ]
)
```

result

```
> db.events.aggregate( [ {$sort:{"timeStamp":1}}, {$group:{_id:{"ifIndex":"$ifsIndex","ip":"$ip"},status:{$push:"$link"},timeStamp:{$push:"$timeStamp"}}}  ])
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "31", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:16", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "28", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:16", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "29", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:16", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "30", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:16", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
{ "_id" : { "ifIndex" : "32", "ip" : "192.168.141.1" }, "status" : [ "1", "1", "1" ], "timeStamp" : [ "19-01-2018 18:12:42", "19-01-2018 18:14:09", "19-01-2018 18:16:33" ] }
>
```

There is a sort to sort the array element in update operations but not in aggregation [doc](http://dochttps://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use this to sort any timestamp field using aggregation, I am sorting it by the latest update time of the document. If you need you can group it later. You can learn more about aggregate [$sort](https://%20https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) here.

```
aggregate.push({ $sort: { updated_at: -1 } });
```

What I do is I make blocks of aggregate actions push them into an array and execute it all together. I find it easier to debug if something is not working properly.